# Incluis https://jazz-soft.net en Ionic (Angular)

Tags: ionic, midi

Me estoy encontrando problemas para incluir esta librería en un proyecto de ionic.

En base a este ejemplo => https://jazz-soft.net/demo/Autoplay.html quiero hacer como primer paso algo parecido.

Hasta ahora esto es lo que he intentado:
Instalo los js necesarios

```
npm install jzz --save
npm install jzz-synth-tiny
npm install jzz-input-kbd
```

Después en angular.json incluyo los scripts

```
"scripts": [
    "node_modules/jzz/javascript/JZZ.js",
    "node_modules/jzz-synth-tiny/javascript/JZZ.synth.Tiny.js",
    "node_modules/jzz-input-kbd/javascript/JZZ.input.Kbd.js"
]
```

Luego en home.page.ts

```
export class HomePage {

JZZ:any;

  constructor() {
    this.cartajzz()

  }
  async cartajzz() {
   this.JZZ = await JZZ.synth.Tiny.register('Web Audio');
  }

}
```

Me dice que JZZ no está definido. Sin embargo si muestro la consola de desarrollo en el navegador veo que los js ya están incluidos...

Lo he escrito asíncrono por si fuera por tiempos de carga, pero evidentemente no parece ser eso. Estoy bastante perdido...

Answer (score 0):

Resuelvo el problema escribiendo esto en el componente home.page.ts:

```
declare var JZZ: any;

import 'node_modules/jzz/javascript/JZZ.js';
import 'node_modules/jzz-synth-tiny/javascript/JZZ.synth.Tiny.js';
import 'node_modules/jzz-input-kbd/javascript/JZZ.input.Kbd.js';
```

No se si es la mejor manera, pero de momento es la que encuentro...